# Sencha 2 native iOS build copy operation failed

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I dont understand why I get this error. And why is it trying to copy the "../webapp" folder to the icon.png image, it looks like the destication and source folders are switched.

```
C:\projectsGit\mybipper\portal\bk-servlets\src\main\webapp\parentapp>sencha package build packager.json
[INFO] Can not open source file
The application was successfully packaged
Bundle Seed ID is missing from config file
Failed to package application

[ERROR] Copy operation failed src=../build\MobileKids.app\webapp\ dst=../build\MobileKids.app\icon.png
```

My packager config:

```
{
    "applicationName":"MobileKids",
    "applicationId":"TC3BU5LD52.com.bipper.mobilekids",
    "versionString":"1.1",
    "iconName:":"icon.png",
    "inputPath":".",
    "outputPath":"../build",
    "configuration":"Debug",
    "platform":"iOS",
    "deviceType":"Universal",
    "certificatePath":"Certificate_key.p12",
    "certificateAlias":"iPhone Developer: Thomas Vervik (TC3BU5LD52)",
    "sdkPath":"C:/Program Files (x86)/Android/android-sdk",
    "orientations": [
        "portrait",
        "landscapeLeft",
        "landscapeRight",
        "portraitUpsideDown"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Huff, nevermind, was my own mistake, I had a : inside the iconName like this:

```
"iconName:":"icon.png",
```